# Finding rate of increase

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

At time=3 hours percentage of A is 2%. At time= 5 hours percentage of A is 8%. How do I calculate the rate of increase of A during the time period from 3-5 hours?
Can someone please explain this as I am not good with percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 3, we have $0.02A$ and, at 5, we have $0.08A$, which correspond to $2\%$ and $8\%$, respectively.  The rate of increase is then

$$\frac{0.08A - 0.02A}{0.02A} = 3.$$

Thus, the increase during the two hours is $3$ times $0.02A$.

Comment: So is the rate of increase 3? Shouldn't I divide by the time difference? Because if at time t1, there was x1 and at t2 there was x2 then rate would be (x1-x2)/(t1-t2) ?

Comment: @sam_fox: 3 is the rate of increase per two hours.  If you divide it by the time difference, then you get an average increase rate per hour, which is 1.5.  Note that this is an "average increase rate" per hour which does not have to be true if the speed with which A is increasing changes over time.  For instance, it may be at time=4 hours percentage of A is 6%, which means that per hour increase rate is decreasing over time